# DataFrame with DatetimeIndex, how to make a plot per year?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I have a dataframe named `df` with `datetimeIndex` the first day of month and a column named `Val` with some numeric values.

```
df.head()


+------------+-----+
|            | Val |
+------------+-----+
| DateTime   |     |
| 2011-10-01 |  11 |
| 2011-11-01 |  85 |
| 2011-12-01 |  12 |
| 2012-01-01 |  91 |
| 2012-02-01 |  44 |
+------------+-----+
```

the dataFrame contains one row per months of the years between 2010 and 2017. My target is to plot in the same graph all the values where each line represent one year, on the x axis I have the months (Jan or 01 is not important) and in the y axis the amount of `Val`.

My first idea was to use something like `df.groupby(df.index.year)['Val'].agg('sum').unstack()` but this produce an error.
AttributeError:

> 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'remove_unused_levels'

Then I wrote the following code, which works but have some problems:

- I have to list all the years;
- I have to list all the color of the line
- It is difficult to create a legend

.

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,7))
months = df['2018'].index
ax1.set_xlabel('months')
ax1.set_ylabel('Sales')
ax1.plot(months, df['2018'], color='navy')
ax1.plot(months, df['2017'], color='blue')
ax1.plot(months, df['2016'], color='lightblue')
ax1.plot(months, df['2015'], color='lime')
plt.grid()

fig.tight_layout()
plt.title('Sales per year', loc='center')

plt.show()
```

is there a smarter way to generate the plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide the DataFrame in a copyable format, I can't produce any figure. Still, you can try the following way. There might be other ways using some sort of `groupby` on the DataFrame

```
start = 2015
end = 2018
years = map(str, range(start, end+1))
colors = ['lime', 'lightblue', 'blue', 'navy']

for year, c in zip(years, colors):
    ax1.plot(months, df[year], color=c)

plt.grid()
fig.tight_layout()
```